# Count number of Postgres statements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to obtain count the number of Postgres Statements my Ruby on Rails application is performing against our database. I found this entry on stackoverflow, but it counts transactions. We have several transactions that make very large numbers of statements, so that doesn't give a good picture. I am hoping the data is available from PG itself - rather than trying to parse a log.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35940/how-many-queries-per-second-is-my-postgres-executing

Comment: You want just a number per second? Aren't you interested in _what_ queries are those and how much time do they take?

Comment: Actually not the number per second. At the moment, just the total number from a large block of code to compare two significantly different approaches. Eventually may need to dig deeper.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [ActiveSupport instrumentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_instrumentation.html#active-record). Part of Rails, this framework is used throughout Rails applications to publish certain events. For example, there's an `sql.activerecord` event type that you can subscribe to to count your queries.

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe "sql.activerecord" do |*args|
    counter++
done
```

You could put this in `config/initializers/` (to count across the app) or in one of the various `before_` hooks of a controller (to count statements for a single request).

(The fine print: I have not actually tested this snippet, but that's how it should work AFAIK.)

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL provides a few facilities that will help.

The main one is [`pg_stat_statements`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstatstatements.html), an extension you can install to collect statement statistics. I strongly recommend this extension, it's very useful. It can tell you which statements run most often, which take the longest, etc. You can query it to add up the number of queries for a given database.

To get a rate over time you should have a script sample `pg_stat_statements` regularly, creating a table with the values that changed since last sample.

The [`pg_stat_database`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-DATABASE-VIEW) view tracks values including the transaction rate. It does not track number of queries.

There's `pg_stat_user_tables`, `pg_stat_user_indexes`, etc, which provide usage statistics for tables and indexes. These track individual index scans, sequential scans, etc done by a query, but again not the number of queries.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I will try both approaches in the coming week.